Windows 11 sometimes doesn't reconnect to Wi-Fi without manual prodding
Sometimes, when I turn on my Wi-Fi hotspot, Windows 11 does not connect to it automatically.
I have to bring up this menu:

Then, click on the > arrow on the Wi-Fi button to show the list of nearby access points. For a moment, the Izu access point doesn't appear. A split second later it spontaneously appears and Windows connects to it.
How do we get Windows 11 to reliably, spontaneously notice the activation of a hot spot and connect to it automatically?

Go through each adapter property and provide us the current value as text. Be sure to format the information the best you can
